# Blazor WASM Hosted: keep getting No service for type 'BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler' has been registered

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I've created a hosted Blazor WASM app that uses Azure AD for authentication and authorization. I am able to login to Azure AD successfully. After I login, I try to navigate to a page that has an API call, and get the error described in the stack trace shown below. I can verify the API endpoint on the Server app has a valid JWT and is authorized, but it doesn't recognize a service type for BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler. See the details I've provided below.

Here's the error and stack trace I'm receiving.
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler' has been registered.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.<>c__4`1.<AddHttpMessageHandler>b__4_1(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder b)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<CreateHandlerEntry>g__Configure|0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder b)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.LoggingHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Configure>b__0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder builder)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandlerEntry(String name)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<.ctor>b__1()    at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)    at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(String name)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(String name)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.AddTransientHelper[TClient,TImplementation](IServiceProvider s, IHttpClientBuilder builder)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`2.<AddTypedClientCore>b__0(IServiceProvider s)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
at lambda_method31(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.BlazorWASM.ServerAPI.ClientHandler[101]
Received HTTP response headers after 1270.7ms - 500
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.BlazorWASM.ServerAPI.LogicalHandler[101]
End processing HTTP request after 1331.1ms - 500
Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

Here's my Program.cs
[Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INRrM.png)

I expect to be able to make a successful HTTP call to the Server API. Instead I get a status code 500 - internal server error every single time, even though the request to the Server has the bearer token attached to it, which is what I think the BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler would be handling anyway.

Comment: Please comment this line :  `builder.Services.AddTransient<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();`

Comment: Thanks Jason! I ended up resolving this before I saw your comment, but this is what I needed to do in the Server app: the instance of this line where I called it in the Client app worked, but I figured out it was the Server app that was giving me the issue. Turns out I didn't need this in the Server app to begin with.

Thanks for contributing to this!

Answer (score 0):

@Jason-Pan had the correct answer: this code below does not belong in the Server side of a Blazor WASM hosted application:

builder.Services.AddTransient();

Thanks Jason!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).